# Isomorphic elliptic curves have the same j-invariant

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic different from $2$ or $3$, and
let $E: y^2 = x^3 +Ax+B$ and $E′: y^2 = x^3 +A′x+B′$ be elliptic curves over $K$.

Assume that $E$ and $E′$ are isomorphic via an invertible linear map $M : \mathbb{P}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$
that maps the infinite point $\mathcal O$ of $E$ to the infinite point $\mathcal O$ of $E'$. I want to show that that $j(E) = j(E′)$.

So what I have tho show is that
$j(E) = 1728\cdot\frac{4A^3}{4A^3+27B^2} = 1728\cdot\frac{4A'^3}{4A'^3+27B'^2} = J(E')$.

My idea was to represent the linear map $M$ as follows:

$M =\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\d&e&f\\ g&h&i\end{bmatrix}$

Since $M * \mathcal O = M[0:1:0] = [b:e:h] = [0:1:0] = \mathcal O$ it should follow than $ b = 0, e = 1$ and $h = 0$.

However, this doesn't seem to lead anywhere, since I don't learn anything useful about the coefficients $A'$ & $B'$ which are used to calculate $j(E')$.

Am I somewhat on the right track, or is this done completely different?

Comment: You need to show that the map has the form $(x,y)\mapsto(c^2x,c^3y)$.

Comment: Read III.1 from Silverman's AEC, it will show you how to finish (if you want to keep using homogeneous coordinates you will have to homogenize some formulas). The main thing is that for $M$ to preserve the Weierstrass form requires even more restrictions on its entries.